# Outlook 2010 integration with Gmail - configure trash location

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail-imap

How can I configure Outlook 2010 to save deleted items to the `Gmail/All Mail` folder instead of the `Gmail/Trash` folder?

I have two computers, both with Outlook 2010 installed.  Using the same Gmail account simultaneously on two different computers,  Computer A saves deleted messages to the `Gmail/Trash` folder, while computer B saves deleted messages to the `Gmail/All Mail` folder.   Because both computers have these different behaviors using the same gmail account, I believe this is behavior is caused by a setting in outlook.

Additionally, computer A has a trashcan icon next to the `Gmail/Trash` folder

[image]

while computer B has the trashcan icon next to the `Gmail/All Mail` folder.  Note these are occurring simultaneously using the same gmail account.

[image]

How can I control this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

To set the folder for Deleted items, go to **File -> Account Settings** and double click on the IMAP account. Click **More Settings** then follow the **Deleted Items** tab to make your selection.

Comment: that solves it, thx